A Lasso-like problem
I need to find all the local minima of the following expression:
$$\min_\mathbf x \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}|x_{i}| + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\top}A\mathbf{x}$$
Here $A$ is a positive definite matrix, and $\lambda_i$ are real constants.
This looks like a Lasso problem, however note that if some of the $\lambda_i$ are negative, it is not convex and there might be several solutions.
I am intersted in small dimensions (2 to 4), and I need a robust algorithm (doesn't matter if it is slow or brute force). Any ideas?

Look up the FISTA algorithm !

Let $x$ be $n$ dimensional.
Let $S = \{-1, 1\}^n$, we can rewrite our optimization problem as follows:
$$\min_{s \in S} \min _x \sum_i \lambda_i s_ix_i + \frac12x^TAx$$
subject to $$s_i x_i \ge 0, \forall i \in \{1, \ldots n\}$$
That is we can solve a quadratic programming problem in each orthant and then collect the best solution in each orthant.
Notice that the solution in each orthant will be unique since $A$ is positive definite.
In total, we just solve $2^n$ quadratic programming problems.

Let me write down the optimality condition in terms of subgradient so that we can verify if a point is stationary.
We desire $$0 \in \partial \left( \sum_i \lambda_i |x_i|+\frac12 x^TAx\right)$$
$$0 \in \left\{ \sum_i \lambda_i \partial |x_i|+Ax\right\}$$
That is for a minimizer $x$, we should obtain $v$ such that
$$-Ax=\sum_i \lambda_iv_ie_i$$
where $v_i \in \begin{cases} \{1\} & , x > 0\\
\{-1\} &, x<0 \\ [-1,1]&, x = 0
\end{cases}$ and $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard unit vector.

Let $x(s)$ be a solution to the inner convex minimization problem (with given $s$). If some coordinates vanish, $x_i(s)=0$, it does not necessarily follow that this $x(s)$ is a local minimum in the original problem. Do you agree? This is the point I'm missing (otherwise I agree with your answer).

ah, I misinterpreted your question as you are trying to find all global minimum. Hmm.... thanks for raising the good point. I haven't figured that part as well.

Regarding the optimality condition you wrote ... doesn't this assume that the objective function is convex? My objective function fails to be convex at the hyperplanes $x_i=0$ whenever the corresponding $\lambda_i<0$.

I think it is similar to the concept of stationary point. convexity is not required.

Yes, stationarity is ok. The problem is with the assumption that "stationarity" implies it is a local minimizer.

true, that is a good point.

On second thought I now believe your stationarity condition is actually sufficient for having a local minima.

Though I'm not sure how to (exhaustively) search for all solutions ...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

We consider a slightly more general problem:
$$\min_\mathbf{x} \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}|x_{i}| + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u})^{\top}A(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u})$$
Now, to build on top of Siong's answer ...
Let $C=A^{-1}$, then the equation rewrites:
$$\sum_{j}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}g_{j} + x_{i}-u_{i}=0$$
To certify a local minima, must find $g_i,x_i$ such that:

$g_i=\operatorname{sign}(x_i)$ whenever $x_i\ne0$.
$g_i\in[-1,1]$ whenever $x_i=0$.

Brute force search algorithm
Let $\mathbf{s}\in\{-1,0,+1\}^{N}$ be a vector of signs and zeros. We can show that if $\lambda_i<0$ then $x_i\ne0$ at a local minimum, therefore we assume that $s_i\ne0$ if $\lambda_i<0$.
We propose to solve the following system of linear equations:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j|s_{j}=0}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}g_{j} + \sum_{j|s_{j}\neq0}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}s_{j} &= u_{i},\quad\text{if }s_{i}=0 \\
x_{i} + \sum_{j|s_{j}=0}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}g_{j} + \sum_{j|s_{j}\neq0}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}s_{j} &= u_{i},\quad\text{if }s_{i}\neq0
\end{align}$$
with respect to the $N$ variables $\{x_{i}\}_{i:s_{i}\neq0}\cup\{g_{i}\}_{i:s_{i}=0}$. The equations:
$$\sum_{j|s_{j}=0}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}g_{j} + \sum_{j|s_{j}\neq0}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}s_{j} = u_{i}$$
for $s_{i}=0$, involve only the $g_{i}$ variables and can be solved for them. Then, having found the $g_{i}$, we first check that $-1\leq g_{i}\leq 1$ is satisfied. Then, we can obtain the $x_{i}$ as:
$$x_{i} = u_{i} - \sum_{j|s_{j}\neq0}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}s_{j} - \sum_{j|s_{j}=0}C_{ij}\lambda_{j}g_{j}$$
At this point, we can also check whether $g_{i}=\operatorname*{sign}(x_{i})$ for these indices $i$. If these conditions are satisfied, we have obtained a true solution.
We can then iterate this procedure through all $3^{N}$ vectors $\mathbf{s}\in\{-1,0,+1\}^{N}$.

Hello, just checking, what is $u_i$?

Ah sorry, in my notes I have a slightly more general problem:$$\min_\mathbf{x} \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}|x_{i}| + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u})^{\top}A(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u})$$
